# How to extract values of a raster stack into separate columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, geospatial, raster, spatial

I have rasters of different vegetation measurements (i.e., canopy height, veg density). I want to stack the layers and use `dplyr` to extract values and assign to different columns. How can I do this? Sample code below. Sorry for not having a reproducible example.

Instead of this:

```
RSF_df.sf <- RSF_df.sf %>%
  mutate(can_cover5m = raster::extract(can_cover5m, RSF_df.sf),
         veg_density1mheight_5m = raster::extract(veg_density1mheight_5m, RSF_df.sf),
         veg_density2mheight_5m = raster::extract(veg_density2mheight_5m, RSF_df.sf),
         veg_density3mheight_5m = raster::extract(veg_density3mheight_5m, RSF_df.sf),
         veg_density4mheight_5m = raster::extract(veg_density4mheight_5m, RSF_df.sf),
         veg_density5mheight_5m = raster::extract(veg_density5mheight_5m, RSF_df.sf),
         veg_density_over5mheight_5m = raster::extract(veg_density_over5mheight_5m, RSF_df.sf))
summary(RSF_df.sf)
```

I want this, but with each veg. measurement in a separate column:

```
all_land_data<-addLayer(can_cover5m,veg_density1mheight_5m,veg_density2mheight_5m,veg_density3mheight_5m,
                        veg_density4mheight_5m,veg_density5mheight_5m,veg_density_over5mheight_5m)

del <- RSF_df.sf %>%
  mutate(all_land_data = raster::extract(raster stack, RSF_df.sf)) #I need values for each veg. measurment in seperate columns
summary(del)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood, I think you are making this more complicated than necessary. If you use the `terra` package, and read all rasters in together, a SpatRaster stack is created. Then, using `terra::extract` to extract values for each feature in a `terra::vect` object will produce a data.frame with columns for each raster layer in the stack.

i.e.

```
library(terra)
veg_stk <- c(rast(veg_density1mheight_5m), rast(veg_density2mheight_5m), rast(veg_density3mheight_5m), rast(can_cover5m)
RSF_vect <- vect(RSF_df.sf)

del <- terra::extract(veg_stk, RSF_vect, fun = mean)  # returns a DF
```

Comment: Micha, I appreciate your help. Will this work if ```RSF_df.sf``` is a simple features object?

Comment: It did extract the raster data to separate columns, but it did not retain all of the data in ```RSF_df.sf```.

Comment: Save the output of the extract into a new data.frame, then cbind the original `RSF_df.sf` with the new data.frame to get all columns in one DF.